# MySQL 5 join from integers in json array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, inner-join

Is there any way to accomplish this with MySQL 5?

I have two tables **users** and **roles**

users

```
 desc users;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| data  | json    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)


 select * from users;
 +------+------------------------------------+
 | id   | data                               |
 +------+------------------------------------+
 |    1 | {"name": "cat", "roleIds": [2, 3]} |
 |    2 | {"name": "dog", "roleIds": [1, 4]} |
 |    3 | {"name": "mouse", "roleIds": [5]}  |
 +------+------------------------------------+
 3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

roles

```
desc roles;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| role_id | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| name    | varchar(64) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select * from roles;
+---------+-------------+
| role_id | name        |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 | Admin       |
|       2 | Supervisor  |
|       3 | Provisioner |
|       4 | Operator    |
|       5 | Relief      |
+---------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I want to amend the json data in the users table with the role names
with results looking like this

```
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | data                                                                         |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | {"name": "cat", "roleIds": [2, 3], "roleNames": "[Supervisor, Provisioner]"} |
|    2 | {"name": "dog", "roleIds": [1, 4], "roleNames": "[Admin, Operator]"}         |
|    3 | {"name": "mouse", "roleIds": [5], "roleNames": "[Relief]"}                   |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: That would be that much easier if the schema was properly normalized...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using `json_set()`, `json_contains()` and `json_arrayagg()`, which are all available in MySQL 5.7 (the latter was introduced in version 5.7.22):

```
select u.id,
    json_set(
        u.data,
        '$.roleNames', (
            select json_arrayagg(r.name)
            from roles r
            where json_contains(u.data, cast(r.role_id as json), '$.roleIds')
        )
    ) as data
from users u
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5tfHSJVTrkMa3GeyEtdRMy/0)**:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"name": "cat", "roleIds": [2, 3], "roleNames": ["Supervisor", "Provisioner"]} |
| 2 | {"name": "dog", "roleIds": [1, 4], "roleNames": ["Admin", "Operator"]} |
| 3 | {"name": "mouse", "roleIds": [5], "roleNames": ["Relief"]} |

It should be pinpointed that MySQL does not guarantee the order in which elements appear in arrays generated by `json_arrayagg()`. This is a limitation that we have to live with as of the current database version.

Comment: Unfortunately I found out I have to use MySQL 5.7.12.  JSON_ARRAYAGG didn't come out till 5.7.22.  Is there any way to do it without that command?  Thank you!